# Help me make this switching transistor circuit is right

Tags: transistors, pnp, schmitt-trigger, synthesizer

I'd like some insight to make sure my circuit's design is at its best. At the moment the circuit is working, but since this is my first time designing a circuit from scratch with transistors, I thought it was better to ask advice and learn along the way.

This project is to implement an envelope generator (EG) looper in a synthesizer I am working on. It consists of a Schmitt trigger inverter that will generate a pulse (GateB in schematic) that will be used to retrigger the envelope. The first PNP transistor of the circuit is there to turn on this pulse.  The second PNP is a NOT gate to invert the pulse back and make it a nice 0-15 V gate (LoopGate in schematic). This is because this synthesizer, contrary to standard synths, is designed with:

- Note On = logic 0 (0V)
- Note Off = logic 1 (+15V)

How can I setup the switching circuit so LoopGate has the same characteristics as the built in gate?

Here are the measurements I made of the original gate:

- Note On = 0.05V, -301.5uA
- Note Off = 14.9V, 0uA

There is no need to have exactly 0-15 V since the EG's threshold is around 8 V, but for the exercise I'd like to learn how to be accurate.

From my understanding, I should aim to be able to provide at least -302 uA from the NOT gate's transistor to the trigger input of the EG circuit. For the on/off switching transistor, since it is only there to drive the NOT gate, I suspect it does not need to provide much current.

Please explain to me what is right and wrong with my circuit, and how to select resistors 1 to 5.

On the first picture (SIMULATED) is the circuit I came up with using LTspice simulation. Unfortunately it didn't work well in real life, so I made some modifications that you can see on the second picture (TESTED). This one works great, but, as I said, I am concerned about the current draw of the switching circuit.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Where is GateL?

Comment: My mistake. GateL is actually LoopGate. Correction has been made.